# excel VBA automation generates jsessionID

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, jsessionid

I am using excel VBA to automate some task that requires login, but it seem that as i submit, they auto assign a jsessionID to it, how can i disable this so that the URL wouldn't auto rewrite?

Comment: Why does processing of jsessionid makes difficulties for you? That is how the website works, you can't change that. Please share URL and your code.

Comment: Hmmm, i have never heard of jsessionid before, the web is www.mfcclub.com, the site functions perfectly under normal browsing, but when using excel vba to access it, a jsessionid is added to the URL, which it think the server doesn't reconize and doesn't allow me to login.